# JasperReports expression evaluation

Tags: jasper-reports, expression

Hi, I am using jasper reports 5.0.0.

the following code in jrxml throws exception

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,###").format($P(xyz))
```

throws an expression evaluation exception.

Where as I change this to

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,###").format(Double.valueOf($P(xyz))),
```

the exception is gone. 
Why?? Any help is appreciated, 
Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the exception you get? Also you might won't to ask, how you can avoid boxing the double all the time.

Comment: @user2173275 What type of ***`xyz`*** parameter?

Comment: @AlexK : xyz is a java.lang.Double

Comment: @BorisBrodski: I just get the exception Error Evaluating expression : at so and so line

Answer (score 0):

In report Parameter Value expression of the Input parameter must be different than Input control value which you are passing through input control.

Comment: Could you please give an example. I am not very sure if I have understood this right